# How to debug nfs client connection timeout?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, nfs

I have 1 nfs-server(10.192.244.109) & 2 nfs-client there.

On one client, both ok to mount the nfs-server directory with `v3` & `v4`, while on another client, it's only ok to mount the nfs-server directory with `v4`, the client reports connection timeout if use `v3`.

- **Client 1 ok for v3 and v4:**

```
root@shubuntu1:~# mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 10.192.244.109:/var/lib/lava/dispatcher/tmp delete
root@shubuntu1:~# umount delete
root@shubuntu1:~# mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4 10.192.244.109:/var/lib/lava/dispatcher/tmp delete
root@shubuntu1:~# umount delete
```

- **Client 2 just ok for v4 but not ok for v3:**

```
root@LAVA-Debug:~# mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4 10.192.244.109:/var/lib/lava/dispatcher/tmp delete
root@LAVA-Debug:~# umount delete
root@LAVA-Debug:~# time mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 10.192.244.109:/var/lib/lava/dispatcher/tmp delete
mount.nfs: Connection timed out

real    2m5.713s
user    0m0.079s
sys     0m0.061s
```

Additional info if helps:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ mount.nfs -V
mount.nfs: (linux nfs-utils 1.3.3)
root@LAVA-Debug:~# mount.nfs -V
mount.nfs: (linux nfs-utils 1.3.3)
```

What could be the possible reason here? Where I can go to take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where I can go to take a look?

Use a packet capture tool (e.g. tcpdump/tshark, Wireshark/termshark) to see the connection attempts, i.e. network packets being sent from the client to the server. Look for those that are re-sent several times but never get replied to.

You might also try enabling verbose RPC call logging on the client machine's kernel (the messages will go to `dmesg`) using the `sysctl sunrpc.rpc_debug=0xFFFF` command.

> What could be the possible reason here?

For NFSv3, it is likely that this will be a connection attempt either to the *portmapper* (rpcbind service), or to one of the dynamic ports (for NFS itself or its auxiliary mountd/statd services). NFSv4 does not have this problem because it uses only a single TCP connection.